# Why are my FBX imports triangulating?

Tags: import, .fbx

Not sure why my FBX imports are triangulating, and I can't really find a solution on this problem

[image: Zbrush model]

[image: Importing fbx into blender]

Comment: Hello, try an Alt J to untriangulate (and also you can try a Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide if you need to simplify)

Answer (score 0):

When exporting FBX from Blender, go in the *Geometry* panel and make sure *Triangulated Faces* is Off (it should be Off by default):

[image]

Same for other softwares you export from, thought it's off-topic here.

There is no option to triangulate FBX on import in Blender, so you should get the mesh as it is in the FBX.